# Explode time duration defined by start and end timestamp by the hour

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

I have a table with work shifts (1 row per shift) that include date, start and end time.
**Main goal: I want to aggregate the number of working hours per hour per store.**

This is what my shift table looks like:

| employee_id | store | start_timestamp | end_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01T07:00 | 2022-01-01T11:30 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-01-01T08:30 | 2022-01-01T12:30 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to "explode" the information into a table something like this:

| hour | employee_id | store | date | scheduled_work (h) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07:00 | 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 08:00 | 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 09:00 | 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 10:00 | 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 11:00 | 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 0.5 |
| 08:00 | 2 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 0.5 |
| 09:00 | 2 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 10:00 | 2 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 11:00 | 2 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 12:00 | 2 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 0.5 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I have tried using a method using cross joins and it consumed a lot of memory and looks like this:

```
with test as (
select 1 as employee_id, 1 as store_id, timestamp('2022-01-01 07:00:00') as start_timestamp, timestamp('2022-01-01 11:30:00') as end_timestamp union all
select 2 as employee_id, 1 as store_id, timestamp('2022-01-01 08:30:00') as start_timestamp, timestamp('2022-01-01 12:30:00') as end_timestamp
)


, cte as (
select ts
     , test.*
     , safe_divide(
        timestamp_diff(
                least(date_add(ts, interval 1 hour), end_timestamp)
            , greatest(ts, start_timestamp)
            , millisecond
            )
    , 3600000
    ) as scheduled_work
from test
         cross join unnest(generate_timestamp_array(timestamp('2022-01-01 07:00:00'),
                                                    timestamp('2022-01-01 12:30:00'), interval 1 hour)) as ts
order by employee_id, ts)


select * from cte
where scheduled_work >= 0;
```

It's working but I know this will not be good when the number of shifts starts to add up. Does anyone have another solution that is more efficient?

I'm using BigQuery.

Comment: you might want to remove **order by** inside **cte** subquery, it'll affect the query performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you might want to remove **order by** inside **cte** subquery, it'll affect the query performance.

And another similar approach:

```sql
WITH test AS (
  select 1 as employee_id, 1 as store_id, timestamp('2022-01-01 07:00:00') as start_timestamp, timestamp('2022-01-01 11:30:00') as end_timestamp union all
  select 2 as employee_id, 1 as store_id, timestamp('2022-01-01 08:30:00') as start_timestamp, timestamp('2022-01-01 12:30:00') as end_timestamp
),
explodes AS (
  SELECT employee_id, store_id, EXTRACT(DATE FROM h) date, TIME_TRUNC(EXTRACT(TIME FROM h), HOUR) hour, 1 AS scheduled_work
    FROM test,
  UNNEST (GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(
            TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(start_timestamp + INTERVAL 1 HOUR, HOUR),
            TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(end_timestamp - INTERVAL 1 HOUR, HOUR), INTERVAL 1 HOUR
         )) h
   UNION ALL
  SELECT employee_id, store_id, EXTRACT(DATE FROM h), TIME_TRUNC(EXTRACT(TIME FROM h), HOUR),
         CASE offset
           WHEN 0 THEN 1 - (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM h) * 60 + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM h)) / 3600
           WHEN 1 THEN (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM h) * 60 + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM h)) / 3600
         END
    FROM test, UNNEST([start_timestamp, end_timestamp]) h WITH OFFSET 
)
SELECT * FROM explodes WHERE scheduled_work > 0;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
with temp as (
  select * replace(
    parse_time('%H:%M', start_time) as start_time, 
    parse_time('%H:%M', end_time) as end_time
  )
  from  your_table
)
select * except(start_time, end_time),
  case 
    when hour = time_trunc(start_time, hour) then (60 - time_diff(start_time, hour, minute)) / 60
    when hour = time_trunc(end_time, hour) then time_diff(end_time, hour, minute) / 60
    else 1 
  end as scheduled_work
from (
  select time_add(time_trunc(start_time, hour), interval delta hour) as hour, 
    employee_id, store, date, start_time, end_time
  from temp, unnest(generate_array(0,time_diff(end_time, start_time, hour))) delta
)
order by employee_id, hour
```

if applied to sample data as in your question

[image]

output is

[image]