# Exploding time range hour-wise in BigQuery

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

I have table with shift start and end times. I'd like to explode it, giving each row an hour and duration of time given in that hour. i.e.

Table "Shift_time":

[image]

Output Result:

[image]

I tried solutions here ([Explode time duration defined by start and end timestamp by the hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73202312/explode-time-duration-defined-by-start-and-end-timestamp-by-the-hour)) but were giving me incorrect results

Comment: Hi @Mohammad Naseer Batla,  If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you can use generate an array of starting hour and end hour of each row. From there you can calculate based on your requirement. You can try the below sample query :

**Query:**

```
  CREATE TEMP TABLE mdata AS (
  SELECT
    '2022-12-15' mdate,
    'abc' code,
    PARSE_TIME("%H:%M:%S","2:15:00") start_time,
    PARSE_TIME("%H:%M:%S","2:21:00") end_time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    "2022-12-15",
    "abc",
    PARSE_TIME("%H:%M:%S","2:45:00"),
    PARSE_TIME("%H:%M:%S","2:55:00")
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    "2022-12-15",
    "abc",
    PARSE_TIME("%H:%M:%S","3:20:00"),
    PARSE_TIME("%H:%M:%S","7:22:00")
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    "2022-12-15",
    "xyz",
    PARSE_TIME("%H:%M:%S","8:18:00"),
    PARSE_TIME("%H:%M:%S","9:25:00") );
WITH
  t2 AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    EXTRACT(hour
    FROM
      start_time)start_hr,
    EXTRACT(hour
    FROM
      end_time)end_hr
  FROM
    mdata )
SELECT
  mdate,
  code,
  new_start_hr hour,
  SUM(timediff)minute
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE
      WHEN new_start_hr BETWEEN start_hr+1 AND end_hr-1 THEN 60
      WHEN new_start_hr = end_hr
    AND new_start_hr > start_hr THEN TIME_DIFF(end_time,TIME(new_start_hr, 0, 0),minute)
      WHEN new_start_hr < end_hr AND new_start_hr = start_hr THEN TIME_DIFF(TIME(new_start_hr+1, 0, 0),start_time,minute)
    ELSE
    TIME_DIFF(end_time,start_time, minute)
  END
    timediff
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      t2,
      UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(start_hr, end_hr)) new_start_hr ) )
GROUP BY
  mdate,
  code,
  new_start_hr
ORDER BY
  mdate,
  code,
  new_start_hr
```

**Output:**
[image]